# Is every sublattice of $O_K$ either an order or an ideal?

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, integer-lattices

So I'm aware that $O_K$ is a lattice in Minkowski space, say in $n$ dimensions when $[K: \mathbb{Q}]=n$, and that ideals and orders are sublattices of $O_K$ of full rank (or as Neukirch calls it, *complete* sublattices).  However, imagining $O_K$ as these discrete lattice points, it's clear that there could be a wide number of sublattices appearing in $O_K$.

My suspicion for this problem is that there are sublattices that do **not** correspond to any ideal since ideals are not just sublattices, but must also have the condition of multiplicatively absorbing elements of $O_K$.  However, while an order also satisfies the ring properties, these are proven from their lattice properties, so I'm doubtful that a sublattice containing $1$ could not be an order.

This is primarily just a curiousity, as I've only just started learning algebraic number theory.

Comment: Since $L$ is of finite index $n$ in $O_K$ it contains  $nO_K$ and hence it is a $\Bbb{Z}+nO_K$ ideal. $\Bbb{Z}+ in \Bbb{Z} = \Bbb{Z}[in]$ is a subring of $\Bbb{Z}[i]$ and $m(\Bbb{Z}+n i \Bbb{Z} )$ is a $\Bbb{Z}[in]$-ideal but not a $\Bbb{Z}[id]$-ideal for any $d < n$. Containing $1$ is not sufficient for being a subring try with $\Bbb{Z} + 2^{1/3}\Bbb{Z}+ 2^{2/3}3\Bbb{Z}$ which is a $\Bbb{Z}[2^{1/3}3]$ ideal. To classify the orders look at the rings between $O_K$ and $\Bbb{Z}+n O_K$ (corresponding to the subrings of $O_K/(n)$).